# How to make button as one of the column inside table component in CDE Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I am trying to make the table component with the button inside the table column in CDE Pentaho. How can it be achieved?

Comment: @Pamblam: where to write this code for table component in pentaho CDE?

Comment: oh you know, in the middle somewhere.

Comment: please give the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will need some work.
In the Draw function of your table, you may put some javascript to manipulate the DOM and add your button : as far as I remember, the draw function receives a parameter that is a structure with the column and row index of the current cell.

Try first this code in the draw function :

```
function(paramdraw) {
      console.log(paramdraw);
}
```

and look for the content of paramdraw iin the console.

Maybe there is a better way to do it...

Comment: I didn't saw any draw function in my table component of CDE pentaho. Where can I find that?

Comment: Look at the advanced properties

Answer (score 0):

What we do here usually is something like editing the query on the datasource with a column that output the HTML code for a button.

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    NAME, 
    concat('<input type="button" onclick="alert(',ID,')">click me</input>') as button 
FROM 
    foo 
WHERE 
    bar='bar';
```

That should display a button. If you are not using a query as datasource, but a transformation the idea is the same. Just make the output contains a string that when interpreted by the browser is a button.

Hope it helps. =)